# Adobe AIR - Dynamic SWF Value for content tag in descriptor file

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, flex3

We have a swf based AIR application. From Descriptor file we are loading a swf file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/32.0">  
    <id>com.test.HelloWorld</id>
    <filename>HelloWorld</filename>
    <name>HelloWorldApplication/name>
    <versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>
    <initialWindow>
        <content>HelloWorld.swf</content>
....
```

As you can see we are directly referring locally present HelloWorld.swf file like this `<content>HelloWorld.swf</content>` while bundling our application.

The problem we are facing is, we have different .swf file for different environment like non prod and prod.

Is there a provide dynamic value to `<content>` tag so that it can automatically decide which .swf to pick either from server or local.

Comment: Why would it pick automatically? You, the person, must decide if you want local or https  located SWF and use correct descriptor file. Maybe have two copies (using local and using https) then use the one you want. If your problem is not that simple please explain the **why it is needed to be automatic** part more clearly ...

Comment: Alternately, you can make your main SWF a loader that decides, based on environment, which it is, dev or prod, and load the appropriate application from appropriate location.

Comment: Hi @VC.One 
Scenario is we will be having Adobe AIR Bundled Application present in specific location in client machine. We have a SSO URL from where client needs to  authenticate themselves after which from browser we will open Adobe AIR Bundled Application using Custom URI scheme.

Now there are different SSO URLs for production and non-production. So client can open any of the URLs which after authentication will open Adobe AIR Bundled Application. In Adobe AIR Bundled Application we need to load SWF depending upon SSO URL.

Is there a way to load HelloWorld.swf from server?

Answer (score 0):

Use SWF loader mechanism.
However this won't work if you target iOS but works on Windows and Android